# Why does "on-the-fly" casting give me a compile error in Java?

Tags: java, casting

I'm coming from a Python background and working through some Java tutorials (new to the language) and struggling to understand an error I'm getting.

This code works just fine:

```
fahrString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the temperature in F");
fahr = new Double(fahrString);
cel = (fahr - 32) * 5.0/9.0;
```

But this code also works perfectly...

```
fahrString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the temperature in F");
cel = (Double(fahrString) - 32) * 5.0/9.0;
```

...yet gives a compiler error:

```
TempConvGUI.java:12: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method Double(java.lang.String)
location: class TempConvGUI
        cel = (Double(fahrString) - 32) * 5.0/9.0;
               ^
1 error
```

Why is that? I can understand if Java says casting things as needed is a no-go, but then why is my program compiling and running perfectly?

Comment: I guess fahr is declared as double primitive?

Comment: I don't understand completely. You say the compiler gives an error, but you also say the program compiles perfectly. That sounds like a contradiction to me. Maybe you are still running some older version, because the second snippet really won't work.

Comment: How can code that does not compile work perfectly?!

Comment: I've figured out why the program still runs - I'm using Sublime Text 2, and on a compile error, it goes ahead and runs the old version of the .class. I'm glad I realised this now, it would probably have caused a lot of headaches later on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This constructs a new double:

`fahr = new Double(fahrString);`

The inline equivalent would be:

`cel = (new Double(fahrString) - 32) * 5.0/9.0;`

which for the record, is not a cast, but the creation of a new object which parses the string.  No language I know of (even python) lets you cast from String to double.  In python there is just no new operator and so:

`cel = double(fahrString)`

would still be creating a new object.

Comment: Thanks, I was confusing casting with creating an object.

Answer (score 4):

IF you want to cast it to double try as follows

```
((double)fahrString - 32) * 5.0/9.0;
```

Or

```
((Double)fahrString - 32) * 5.0/9.0;
```

I think it is better to use `Double.parseDouble(fahrString)` since as far as I  can see you are trying to cast String to double.

The way you tried is wrong,That's not the way of casting.

Comment: This does not answer my question at all. It also gives the same error as before.

Comment: I see what you're saying, but it doesn't answer my question. It fixes my code, but it doesn't answer what I'm actually asking.

Comment: `fahrString` is a `String`, because `JOptionPane.showInputDialog()` returns a `String`. How can you cast it to double?

Comment: @henrebotha Compilation error means your code is wrong, That is the best explanation. we don't call what you did is casting

Comment: @RenéLink: I don't know, I'm very new to this! :P

Answer (score 2):

Casting is done like this:

```
(Double)fahrstring
```

Not like this:

```
Double(fahrstring)
```

Java interprets the latter as you attempting to call a method named `Double`, which is the reason why it complains it can't find the symbol (you don't have a method called `Double`)

By the way, if there is no specific reason to use `Double`, I'd recommend to use the primitive equivalent `double` instead.

Comment: Thank you, this helps a lot. The tutorial I'm busy with is specifically talking about primitives vs objects so that's probably why they use `Double`.

Comment: @henrebotha How can you say this helps, but Ruchira's answer doesn't?  That makes no sense.  While this explanation may be more informative, the code is the same.

Comment: Because the explanation is more informative. I wasn't asking how to cast things properly, I was asking why the method I was using was giving an error AND running.

Comment: @henrebotha I think it is make sense, what you do is not the casting

Comment: @EdgarBoda: No, I wasn't. Read my question again.

Answer (score 0):

You just missed some brackets ;)

```
fahrString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the temperature in F");
cel = ((Double)fahrString - 32) * 5.0/9.0;
```

Answer (score 0):

`Double.parseDouble(String)` to convert your String literal to a Double value, provided String value is valid for double conversion

```
cel = (Double.parseDouble(fahrString) - 32) * 5.0/9.0;
```

**This is the easiest way of parsing String to a double value.**  This will throw NPE when passed String literal is null / NumberFormatException when the passed String literal is not a valid String for doing the double conversion

Comment: What's the difference between using `parseDouble()` vs using a cast or instantiating a new `Double` object?

Comment: parseDouble(Str) used to convert a double value in String format to an actual double value. i.e. "98.0" -> 98.0. This will not create any new instance of Double object, instead it will return double primitive value. There are two type of cast. i.e. upcast and downcast. it is useful when you want to transfer bytes from one container to another container. Since String and Double are containers of equal byte size, they are allowed to be cast by the compiler

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
cel = ((Double.parseDouble(fahrString)) - 32) * 5.0/9.0;
```